# How do I allow a 3rd party (twilio) access to current user account in laravel

Tags: laravel, twilio

I am making an application using laravel and twilio that gets feedback about student performance. The logic as follows.

1. A user, in my case the Student(called resident) logs in and uses a
   web page form to send an eval request to a teacher (called
   attending). This step starts a session and saves teacher info and
   student info.

   2. A random question is picked from a database and saved to the session.
   3. The phone number of the teacher is pulled from a database and the random question is pulled from session and sent to the teacher on SMS using twilio.
   4. The teacher responds with yes, no, or DNS (did not see) via Twilio SMS.
   5. The teacher's response along with the student name, the teacher name and the question asked are saved to a database.

My application works up until step 5. The problem is that a new session is being started when the teacher responds via SMS. So everything after the response is saved to a new session. I can't get access to the original session.  I think I need a way to automatically grant the teacher access to the student(ie. user's account). This seems to be a problem with it being a 3rd party application. Can this be done or is there another way to accomplish this? 
Below is the code I am using for the response. It is not able to access the session that contains the residentName, the firstQuestion, or the attending_name data. It puts null for those values and uploads null to the database. How do I get access to the initial session in this situation?

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Session;
use Twilio\Rest\Client;
use Twilio\Twiml;
use App\Question;
use App\Answer;

class AskFirstQuestionsController extends Controller
{

public function qOneResponse(Request $request) {

    $responderNumber = $request->input('From');
    session()->put('responderNumber', $responderNumber);
    session()->save();
    $responderAnswer = strtolower($request->input('Body')); 
    $residentName = session::get('residentName');
    $firstQuestion = session::get('first_question');
    $attending_name = session::get('attending_name');

    if (strpos($responderAnswer, 'yes') !== false) {
        $answer = new 
         Answer(['attending'=>$attending_name,'resident_name'=>$residentName,'question_body' 
         =>$firstQuestion, 'answer_yes'=>1]);
        $answer->save(); 
        $smsResponse = "Great! Please help us reinforce this action by providing specific feedback 
        to the resident about what they did. Thank You for teaching!";

    } else if (strpos($responderAnswer, 'no') !== false) {
        $answer = new
        answer::create(['attending'=>$attending_name,'resident_name'=>$resident_name,'question_body' 
        =>$firstQuestion, 'answer_no'=>1]);  
        $answer->save();
        $smsResponse = "Ugh, ok...we will work on this. If you feel comfortable, please help us by 
        providing specific feedback to the resident about what they need to work on. Thank You for 
        teaching!";

    } else if (strpos($responderAnswer, 'dns') !== false) {
        $answer = new
        answer::create(['attending'=>$attending_name,'resident_name'=>$resident_name,'question_body' 
        =>$firstQuestion, 'answer_dns'=>1]);
        $answer->save();
        $smsResponse = "How about trying a different question?";

    } else {

        $smsResponse = 'Please answer yes, no or dns.';
    }

    return response($this->respond($smsResponse))->header('Content-Type', 'application/xml');
}

public function respond($smsResponse) {
    //get responderNumber and use it below
    $responderNumber = session::get('responderNumber');
    $response = new Twiml();
    $response->message($smsResponse, ['to' => $responderNumber]);
    return $response;

}
```

Do I need to do some type of multiauth approach and somehow grant the teacher automatic access to the student's account (user account)? Or do I have to re-write the logic so that the response-request lifecycle closes and then try to write to the database (maybe it will then use the original session data?)? Or is there a simpler way? Please help. I have been stuck for more than a week.

Comment: What's your plan if two students send this at the same time to the same teacher?

Comment: I think I will likely need to have a separate phone number for each student, or a way to match up the sender with the recipient but according to the Twilio documentation this is much tougher to do. However, I am unable to get it to work for a single student because of the problem above.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I'm not a Laravel developer, but session objects in web application frameworks like this are normally tied to a cookie that either stores the contents of the session or an ID for the session which points to the contents in a database in order to add state to a user's  session within a browser.

When Twilio receives an incoming SMS message the webhook that is sent to your server is not connected to the browser session that the user is part of, so you cannot access the same data.

Instead of using the session, you should store this as part of your actual database so that you can look up the details from the database when you receive the SMS.